# Having trouble making buttons input only into the input field that is active (or cursor blinking)

Tags: input, cursor, cursor-position, input-field

I have an application (built with HTML, CSS, and JS) with 3 input fields each of which accepts numbers (1 -9, and 0). I also have buttons 1 thru 9 (and 0, similar to calculator). Having trouble making the buttons input only into the input field that is active (or cursor blinking). I have tried selecting buttons to input in the input field by changing the value, but this only works for one input field at a time.

I'd appreciate your insight into this.

Thank you!

Vusal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please tell us a little bit more about the problem, so you may receive answers.  We cannot guess what context this applies to.  Are you looking at some program (what language) or script?   Also "Having trouble" indicates that you've tried some things that didn't work.  Please indicate what you've tried and what the result was.  At least enough, again, for us to understand how to help you.  Also consider editing the question and applying additional tags (more than just "input-field") so that this will be reviewed by the appropriate experts.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my question.